# Open file explorer on mouse hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is that possible to open the file explorer when mouse hover on file explorer icon and close when it leaves the section?

[image]

when mouse cursor leave the file explorer section it auto close .  is this kind of settings available in vscode?

Answer (score 1):

As of today such a setting does not exist. You can subscribe to this [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3742) on the official repo for potential updates.

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=venryx.vscode-vtools) will allow you to close the sidebar by clicking in your editor groups. I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Just press ctrl + B on your keyboard and explorer section get hide. And to get it back you have to press ctrl + shift + E or click on file explorer icon in activity bar